# How do I save a photo from an eBay listing?

Tags: ebay

I wish to reuse a past eBay listing but as it is over 90 days old, eBay will not let me edit it, therefore I want to save the photos from the listings so that I can upload them to a new listing.

But when I right-click on the image, I can't download it. The property tab in Internet Explorer just says "jscript" rather than a URL for the image.

Comment: Can you just download the images locally and then create new listing with them?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @DoNotInstall Open the page in Chrome and then use the Web Inspector to get the image’s URL.

Answer (score 6):

The trick to viewing the full res images is to *double* click on one!

That opens up a viewer where you can page through all the images and right-click to save-as the full resolution versions.

Answer (score 4):

Open the item page -> press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> -> Go to Resources tab, check under images.

[image]

Comment: Which web browser? Mac or Windows? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What works best will depend on how the image is hosted in the page. Some images are from eBay directly, others are embedded from external hosters like Auctiva in various ways. This will affect what methods will work to extract it.

My own general approach in order is:

1. Try to right click & save as
2. Use a screenshot program (like [Snipping Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots), part of Windows). But if you think there is a better higher resolution image that is being shrunk by the browser this is not ideal.
3. Use the web page inspection tools in the browser ([such as noted in this other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26989/177385)). This almost always works but requires the most effort.

Answer (score 1):

I found this looking for the same answer and found this web link. It actually works and downloads ALL eBay item images for you to view on the web page and also download locally by right clicking each image a schoose 'save image'. You will need to change each image filename though as they are saved as all the same name

No software to install and more importantly FREE and WORKS

http://ebaydownload.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a way to BACKUP all your listings/items images and details. Search ebay for LISTING BACKUP SERVICE and you will find what you need. Does NOT require your login information to be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used on my Macbook Air:

1. Double click on the eBay photo
2. Right click on the expanded photo, and select "Save Image As"
3. I saved the file in the "Downloads" folder as a JPEG file
4. Open the Image file normally in your application (from the "Downloads" folder)

Answer (score -2):

Most smart phones have a ScreenShot or Clip Now feature , that allows the user to save whatever is currently displayed on their screen. Open any eBay ad , click on the image you want the save , and swipe the top edge of your phone , to instantly store that image in your photos. Once you've saved the images , you can perform all editing functions as desired . K.I.S.S. (Keep It Simple Stupid)

Comment: The question is about desktop browsing.